# Getstream Bad iOS documentation

Tags: swift, getstream-io

Ok, So I'm trying to add in GetStream to an application which will allow users to comment. Firstly struggling to understand the "backwards" grammar of the documentation I'm also struggling to get a method working correctly (This is down to bad documentation) as all I'm trying to do is check if a user is following a specific feed:

```
userFeed!.following(filter: [FeedId(feedSlug: "element", userId: uuid)], limit: 1) { result in}
```

The above fails with the following reason:

`Cannot convert return expression of type 'Cancellable' to return type 'Bool'`

This is a snippet from their own docs:

```
user1.following(filter: [FeedId(feedSlug: "user", userId: "42"),
                     FeedId(feedSlug: "user", userId: "43")], limit: 2) { result in /* ... */ }
```

Has anyone worked with GetStream who can help with this?

Thanks

Comment: It works for me. Can you show more context of your code?

Comment: Sure: This is the only other piece of code that has interaction with the userFeed and is set at initialisation - Which GetStream returns a success on. `userFeed = Client.shared.flatFeed(feedSlug: "user", userId: "\(user.id)")`

Comment: I recommend you don't use `userId: "\(user.id)"`. It always should be the current user id. So, how it's possible that you get `Bool` where the `following` returns discardable `Cancellable`? Can you confirm you store user feed as an instance variable?

Comment: `user.id` is an assigned value outside of GetStream and our own id value. But I can remove for brevity. Unknown how Cancellable is declaring itself a Bool, perhaps it defaults to `isCancelled`, Managed to address this issue by providing the ending method to the block - `{ result in }.cancel() - Whether this will result in it not checking is for another thread. The documentation could do with thickening out on these things

Comment: Also this may cause issues when attaching follows to a given activity within a feed as when attempting to follow a group results in the following error: `Optional(FeedConfigException[6] Status Code: 400, "d22bff18-e6f4-4ffc-a4fe-9bbcf5f086ac" is not a valid feed group)`

Comment: Can you enable logs and show it?
`Client.config = .init(apiKey: "<#ApiKey#>", appId: "<#AppId#>", logsEnabled: true)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204423/discussion-between-user7684436-and-buh).

Comment: {"detail":"\"element:d22bff18-e6f4-4ffc-a4fe-9bbcf5f086ac:32183\" is not a valid feed","status_code":400,"code":4,"exception":"InputException","duration":"0.50ms"}
STREAM: Optional(InputException[4] Status Code: 400, "element:d22bff18-e6f4-4ffc-a4fe-9bbcf5f086ac:32183" is not a valid feed) - Also pinged this into a chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your logs the issue is more clear. The feed id can't contain more than 1 colon.

Comment: Yeah - this solved it on following an 'item' feed. The problem now concerns a feed. as the user should now be able to post an activity on any feed within the app - I believe this is configurable, but only by contacting support.